# Find the my desire plot for ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a scatterplot in `ggplot2`. However, I did not find out how to make my ultimate scatter plot.

If you run the R code with the dataset below "TBV1.txt", you will see the plot. If you consider the purple point in the plot which regarded to the Anim1 on x axis, I want to shift that purple point to the center which is exactly on the vertical line in the middle of the plot. Then, the rest of points regarding to this shifting will  surrounding the purple point.

Could you give me a suggestion how could I do it? In addition, I also will attach the dataset and the R program that I got this plot. do you think modifying this R code can give my desire plot?

```
library(grid)
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)

ss <- read.table("TBV1.txt",header = TRUE)
attach(ss)

b1<-ggplot(ss, aes(x=ID, y=TBV, color=Group,size=TBV)) +
  geom_jitter(position=position_jitter(0.3))+ xlab("Best Animal") + ylab("TBV Values") + ggtitle("") + 
  scale_color_discrete(name = "Group Level")

print(b1)
```

### Dataset file:"TBV1.txt"

```
ID  AnimID  TBV Group
Anim1   46545   1.564848    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   47447   2.021213    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   47452   1.190274    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   47541   1.025038    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   47595   1.642635    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   47721   1.4966  Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   47777   0.757948    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   48072   0.494221    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   48158   1.145181    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   48180   0.853342    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   48856   2.312334    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   48901   1.49454 Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   49252   0.792544    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   49316   1.589449    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   49355   1.849835    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   49366   1.615332    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   49656   1.73856 Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   49727   1.117235    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   49769   0.536753    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   49773   1.895599    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   49820   2.042025    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   49856   2.149416    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   50106   1.5683  Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   50398   0.726094    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   50450   2.239882    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   50821   1.384881    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   51254   0.468043    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   51356   0.367031    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   51465   1.7357  Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   52015   1.424809    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   52121   0.730174    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   52485   0.716409    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   52573   0.38916 Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   53230   1.352233    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   53389   1.865103    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   53556   -0.163423   Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   53651   1.371785    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   53894   0.972286    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   53969   0.962242    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   54057   0.502399    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   54720   1.239072    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   54869   1.35958 Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   55074   1.903243    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   55184   1.760572    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   55289   1.821192    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   55455   1.398092    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   55564   1.608354    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   55928   2.07984 Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   55949   2.251825    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   55951   1.784223    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   56165   2.34612 Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   56523   0.843988    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   56654   1.84453 Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   56757   1.157245    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   56821   1.056802    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   56864   1.382028    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   56915   1.030436    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   56923   1.595493    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   56962   1.226185    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   57303   1.018069    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   57477   1.309901    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   57716   1.739054    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   57737   1.119489    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   57898   1.104568    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   58094   1.801297    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   58254   1.607398    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   58269   2.17588 Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   58335   1.847848    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   58426   1.781369    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   58704   2.270906    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   58729   1.274592    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   58749   1.485773    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   58845   0.962652    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   59125   1.882016    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   59162   1.942503    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   59174   0.750822    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   59253   1.545588    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   59318   0.915935    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   59445   1.828562    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   59499   1.355698    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   60014   1.595345    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   60056   1.496742    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   60057   1.763686    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   60186   0.925772    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   60347   0.911981    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   60674   1.128057    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   60759   1.489789    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   61032   2.927886    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   61175   1.782051    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   61399   1.318839    Anim1rc8085.high650
Anim1   47099   1.180385    Anim1rc8590.high650
Anim1   47578   1.0676  Anim1rc8590.high650
Anim1   48106   1.898607    Anim1rc8590.high650
Anim1   49088   1.822606    Anim1rc8590.high650
Anim1   49307   1.454201    Anim1rc8590.high650
Anim1   49374   2.324009    Anim1rc8590.high650
Anim1   49573   2.018634    Anim1rc8590.high650
Anim1   49757   1.769592    Anim1rc8590.high650
Anim1   51577   1.451644    Anim1rc8590.high650
Anim1   52011   0.813521    Anim1rc8590.high650
Anim1   52135   1.927702    Anim1rc8590.high650
Anim1   52690   1.36903 Anim1rc8590.high650
Anim1   54265   1.331152    Anim1rc8590.high650
Anim1   54267   1.576529    Anim1rc8590.high650
Anim1   54497   1.891641    Anim1rc8590.high650
Anim1   54656   1.701011    Anim1rc8590.high650
Anim1   54707   1.586344    Anim1rc8590.high650
Anim1   56711   1.586944    Anim1rc8590.high650
Anim1   57152   1.673363    Anim1rc8590.high650
Anim1   58093   2.074895    Anim1rc8590.high650
Anim1   59695   0.970035    Anim1rc8590.high650
Anim1   59702   0.971871    Anim1rc8590.high650
Anim1   59784   1.787217    Anim1rc8590.high650
Anim1   60134   1.508719    Anim1rc8590.high650
Anim1   60691   1.674558    Anim1rc8590.high650
Anim1   60940   0.980665    Anim1rc8590.high650
Anim1   49265   1.590452    Anim1rc90.high650
Anim1   51105   1.780677    Anim1rc90.high650
Anim1   57020   1.547244    Anim1rc90.high650
Anim1   57922   1.498998    Anim1rc90.high650
Anim1   61034   0.960186    Anim1rc90.high650
Anim1   47652   1.265   SelectedAnimal
```

Answer (score 1):

You are jittering your data points, and then hoping the final one is in the center. This won't work. Also, `attach` is almost never recommended.

To fix your plot, we can set the `x` values to be a random number for all the values, except your reference point. The way I have done this is adding `x = c(rnorm(nrow(ss)-1, sd = 0.3), 0)` to your aes call. It works by taking n-1 random numbers with an sd of 0.3, and then a 0. It will only work if your reference value is last, but is easily modified in case it isn't. Then we just need to set the x limits to be symmetrical : `xlim(c(-1,1))`

```
ggplot(ss, aes(x = c(rnorm(nrow(ss) - 1, sd = 0.3),0), y = TBV, color = Group, size = TBV)) +
    geom_point() +
    xlab("Best Animal") +
    ylab("TBV Values") +
    ggtitle("") + 
    scale_color_discrete(name = "Group Level") +
    xlim(c(-1,1))
```

[image]